# Capturing single finger scroll for iframes on mobile safari

Tags: iframe, mobile-safari

Is it possible to have an iframe capture the standard (single-finger) scroll on mobile safari? I  have a javascript application that creates a large iframe intended for scrolling. It works great an standard web browsers, but requires the unintuitive two-finger scroll when using mobile Safari.